# Not able to place order with stripe magento extension on local developement

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

My first doubt is will stripe work on local wamp server to test?
I am getting an error in my console that says

> TypeError: can't assign to properties of (new
>   String("payment%5Bmethod%5D=foggyline_stripe&payment%5Bcc_type%5D=AE&payment%5Bcc_number%5D=378282246310005&payment%5Bcc_exp_month%5D=7&payment%5Bcc_exp_year%5D=2023&payment%5Bcc_cid%5D=4526")): not an object

Comment: sure it will work in your local server but in your local pc must have internet working.

Comment: I have internet but still not working

Comment: which extension you are using for stripe? have you enabled test mode?

Comment: I just made it from tutorial

Comment: This is the code where i tried from https://github.com/ajzele/Foggyline_Stripe